# How to set data from jQuery plugin to data base ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery plugin "Slider", and this slider show current price item, and I want to add posibility to change prices data by jQuery slider and update it at data base.

There is a model:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Controller, where I added method "SetPrice", for update and save data from ajax post method. But I do not know, it is correct way or not for getting data from javascript.

```
 public class ItemsController : Controller
{
    private ItemsContext db = new ItemsContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = db.Items.ToList();
        return View(items);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        var item = db.Items.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(item);
    }

    public void SetPrice(Item item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new Exception("Some exception");
        db.Items.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

}

View "Details" where I show current data item by slider, and want to add a logic for change data Price slider.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.css">
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/CustomScripts/SliderJs.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>


    <script>
        var myApp = myApp || {};
        myApp.item = @Model.Price
    </script>
 <script src="~/CustomScripts/SliderJs.js"></script>
   

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

This is how it looks at Details view.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTtpY.png)

And section scripts.

I changed from this:

```js
(function ($, window, myApp) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#slider").roundSlider({
            radius: 90,
            width: 10,
            handleSize: "+10",
            sliderType: "range",
            value: myApp.item
        });
    });
})(jQuery, window, myApp);
```

To this, added an ajax post method but something goes wrong, even slider don`t show current date.

```js
(function ($, window, myApp) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#slider").roundSlider({
            radius: 90,
            width: 10,
            handleSize: "+10",
            sliderType: "range",
            value: myApp.item,
        });
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Items/SetPrice',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { value: value},
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: "json",
            })
        });
    });
})(jQuery, window, myApp);
```

I`m looking for any advices, how to change properly a method "SetPrice" and script. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding [this documentation](https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/jQuery-Circular-Range-Slider-Plugin-roundSlider.html) I guess you should subscribe to the `change` event and post your value to the server (using ajax there). You should also use `Price` instead of `value` when sending data back to object. Otherwise it would not bind to your `Item` object in `SetPrice` action. Also think about how you will find the proper Item to update the price. You should probably add an id along with price.

So that your slider initialization should look somehow like this (note I have not tested that):

```
$("#slider").roundSlider({
    radius: 90,
    width: 10,
    handleSize: "+10",
    sliderType: "range",
    value: myApp.item,
    change: function(value)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Items/SetPrice',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { Price: value},
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for answer, to update item price I have tried this, <dd id="Price" data-price="@Model.Price">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
        </dd>   but it`s not working